# C++ Detect and translate keypress to virtual keycode

Tags: c++, keycode

Im making a program where the user hits a keyboard key and then i need detect keypress and translate the keypress to virtual keycode (VK_KEY)

Been searching very long but without success.
something like:

```
cout << "Press a key: ";
keypress=getch();

*translate getch() to (VK_KEYS)*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

`getch` is a non-standard function very similar to `getc`, which returns a **character**.

Virtual key codes do not map to characters one to one. There exist key codes which produce no character at all, and key codes which produce a *different* character in case another key was pressed previously or is being held down, etc etc.
Also, some very different virtual keys (think numpad!) can, and *will* produce the same character.

So, you have a many-to-few mapping, and the pidgeonhole principle applies.

You can, of course, make a lookup table for *some* characters (such as A-Z), and that may be just good enough for what you want. But there is generally no way of doing this correctly.

Comment: alright thanks. So if I use getch, user pressed for example F, is it possible to convert that using a list and then put the virtual keycode into: if(GetAsyncKeyState()???